# Facebook Wall Post is not showing on friends news feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

I have created a facebook application for sending messages.I am posting some content and image to my wall using php facebook feed code.Normally when i post something on my wall it will visible on my friends news feed.But my wall post is not visible on my friends news feed.The code for posting wall is

```
$AccessToken       = $this->facebook->getAccessToken();
    $attachment = array(
    'access_token' => $AccessToken,
    'message' => "$Msg",
    'name' => 'some content',
    'link' => $link,
    'picture' => "$ShareImage",
    'description' => '',
    'caption'=>'',
    'properties' => array (
                              'Send one to a friend now:' => array  (
                                        'text' => 'Facebook App ',
                                        'href' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/appname/'
                                       ),
                              'Become a fan:' => array  (
                                        'text' => 'Page Name',
                                        'href' => 'http://www.Facebook.com/page/'
                                       )
```

);

```
 $send = $this->facebook->api("/".$fbid."/feed", 'POST', $attachment);
```

Is this because of any permission missing...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By their nature, wall posts containing media are not status updates. If a wall post contains media, users will need to visit your Page in order to see it. If you would like a status update to show in people's Newsfeeds, you will need to remove media (for instance link previews).

Keep in mind this is not a bug. Rather, it is how Facebook's API identifies status updates versus wall posts.

Comment: If i remove the picture and link it will show in friends profile?

Comment: I do not believe this answer is accurate.  Posts with media (image) do appear in the news feed.

Comment: I'd love to see a link proving either Sudhir or James right.  And by "right" I mean "right today" because Facebook is Facebook.